# Change the design of a window/div scroll bar

Tags: html, css, scrollbar

I have a div where it has an overflow attribute, everything is fine, but I want the scrollbar to look like this. not the default one, is there anyway I can implement this?

[image]

or do I have to use a css framework?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can apply the same scrollbar from here. Just follow the instructions.

http://rocha.la/jQuery-slimScroll

Answer (score 0):

Since there are no cross browser scrollbar styling availiable in css you need to use jquery libraries to do that for you.

use this library 
https://code.google.com/p/jscrollpane/

simply download this and attach to your project and to the div you want to style the scrollbar 
simply code it as this

```
<div class="styleme"></div>
```

and in your jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('.styleme').jScrollPane();

});
```

Thats all You need to do.
Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

you can use jquery tinyscrollbar plugin

http://baijs.nl/tinyscrollbar/

in Javascript

```
$('#scrollbar1').tinyscrollbar();
```